# How can I define global variables in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to webpack.

Trying to make a build with webpack. Everything is ok, no errors but when i try to start the code in browser it says:

> build.js:118 Uncaught ReferenceError: outputValues is not defined
>       at countIntegers (build.js:118)
>       at Module. (build.js:104)
>       at **webpack_require** (build.js:20)
>       at build.js:84
>       at build.js:87

So, how can i define my global variables in webpack?

// index.js

```
(() => {
'use strict';})();

const outputValues = document.querySelectorAll('.output-values')[0];
const countButton = document.querySelectorAll('.count-button')[0];
const resetButton = document.querySelectorAll('.reset-button-disabled')[0];

import { countIntegers } from './button.js';

const counter = countIntegers();

countButton.addEventListener('click', counter.showNextInteger);
resetButton.addEventListener('click', counter.reset);
```

// button.js

```
export const countIntegers = () => {
  let currentInteger = 0;
    outputValues.innerText = currentInteger;
      return {
        showNextInteger: () => {
         if(currentInteger + 1 > 0) {
           resetButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
           resetButton.disabled = false;
           resetButton.className = 'reset-button-enabled';
          }
            return outputValues.innerText = ++currentInteger;
        },
        reset: () => {
          outputValues.innerText = 0;
          resetButton.style.cursor = 'default';
          resetButton.disabled = true;
          resetButton.className = 'reset-button-disabled';
            return currentInteger = 0;
        }
      };
}
```

// webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: './assets/output/scripts/index.js',

    mode: 'none',

    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/assets/bundle")
    }
};
```

Thank's for help!